# How to work with Knockout Code from a JQuery library file

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, sumoselect.js

I know this is not quite possible or rather feasible. But , this is what I intend to do .

I have a JQuery Plugin named `sumoselect` (https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) for multi select dropdown like feature which has a static link at the bottom.

```
    addSumoSelect: function () {

        $('#intGroup1').SumoSelect({ createNew: true, countList : true});
    }
```

This createNew() is a  function defined in sumoselect JQuery plugin file :

```
            createNew: function () {
                var O = this;
                O.optDiv.append($('<ul><li><a class="ispicon ispicon_plus" href="#addInt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSchedule" data-bind="click:$parent.addGroup" title="Create New"> Create New</a></li></ul>'));

            }
```

But the problem is JQuery is not able to parse `data-bind` and `parent` syntaxes as **I suppose** they are native to Knockout JS.

So , the click event is not being fired.

What can I do to make it work ?

The `addGroup` function is defined in my Knockout JS file.

**UPDATE**

Should I try to do something like :

```
                $("#intrusionGroup1").click(function (element) {
                    element.parentNode.addIntrusion();
                });
```

Comment: jQuery should be able to parse the `data-*` attributes, as they are valid HTML - it just won't know what to do with them. Indeed, it's Knockout that should parse them and you have to somehow notify KO that you've added stuff. Don't really know what's the least hassle free way of doing it. You should realise that you are trying to use Knockout without using Knockout which is, understandably, not a really good approach.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of rendering an HTML content which is wrapped in a string is to use the [html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html), but for that too, you will need to use another knockout binding (unfortunately). So, the easiest way of doing this that I can think of now is to use jQuery itself and register a click event for that list item. For that you will need to make sure to have unique selectors for the list items.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that initializes the widget and injects the custom html. Because a binding's init method is executed during `ko.applyBindings`, it has the chance to inject child elements early enough for them to be data-bound.

A data-bind has an `init` method that is called once when `ko.applyBindings` happens, and an `update` method that is called whenever a linked observable changes.

It would look something like this:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.sumoselect = {
    init: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
      // Initialize the widget, something like:
      var widget = $(element).sumoselect(/* options */);

      // By now, the new HTML should be injected and data-bound
      // after `init` returns


      // I'm not sure if the widget has a dispose method, but
      // it's important to know you'll have to take care of this
      // yourself.
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
        // Something like:
        // widget.destroy()  
      });

    }
};
```

An example that shows you what **won't work**:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  onClick: function() { console.log("CLICK"); }
});

document.querySelector(".myDiv").innerHTML += "<button data-bind='click: onClick'>click me</div>";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Test button:</p>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

---

An example that shows you what **will work**:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.injectButton = {
  init: function(element) {
    element.innerHTML += "<button data-bind='click: onClick'>click me</div>";
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({
  onClick: function() { console.log("CLICK"); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Test button:</p>
<div class="myDiv" data-bind="injectButton"></div>
```

---